# Eclipse double click scope selection and Alt+shift+up not working after installing aptana plugin

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana, aptana3

Double click for scope selection and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> were working fine before installing Aptana Studio plugin, but now both are not working. Is there any setting to enable it again?
I'm using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be key conflicts occurred between original short-cuts and with the Aptana plugins.

Go to Window->Preferences. Type keys in the search box. Type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> in the keys preference page search box. If there are multiple commands registered then check the context of all these commands or assign new short-cut key.

!How to do this!

As you see in the picture. For Alt+Shift+Up keyboard short-cut multiple commands are registered. Change these short-cuts and make them unique.Click on **Binding** text box, delete the content and Hold your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and Press <kbd>0</kbd>.

Make sure that this short cut is not assigned to any other commands.
Now you can do selection scoping using the new short-cut i.e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> while editing java source.
[image]

Comment: I added picture. Tell me what to do